# Can't remove users from specific role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Using web-api 2 and identity 2, I'm trying to create an action to remove a user from roles using user id and role names. I'm using the ApplicationUserManager provided by the nuget identity2 sample.

My action

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("RemoveUserFromRole")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RemoveUserFromRole(UserRolesViewModel model) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    var result = await UserManager.RemoveUserFromRolesAsync(
        model.UserId, model.RoleNames);

    if (result.Errors.Any())
        return InternalServerError(); 

    return Ok();
}
```

My view model:

```
public class UserRolesViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IList<string> RoleNames { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUserManager's RemoveUserFromRolesAsync:

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> RemoveUserFromRolesAsync(
    string userId, IList<string> roles) 
{
    var userRoleStore = (IUserRoleStore<ApplicationUser, string>) Store;

    var user = await FindByIdAsync(userId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (user == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid user Id");

    var userRoles = await userRoleStore.GetRolesAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
    foreach (var role in roles.Where(userRoles.Contains))
        await userRoleStore.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return await UpdateAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

My issue is that given a user belonging to the roles 'User' and 'Mod', the user cannot be removed from 'Mod'. Posting the following json removes the user from the role 'User' as expected:

```
{
    "userId": "0d5f97e4-65a0-43ad-b889-0af98a7ff326",
    "roleNames": [
        "User"
    ]
}
```

But given the following json, user is not removed from 'Mod', but is instead removed from 'User':

```
{
    "userId": "0d5f97e4-65a0-43ad-b889-0af98a7ff326",
    "roleNames": [
        "Mod"
    ]
}
```

Debugging shows that when given the role 'Mod', the correct user id and role name are passed into userRoleStore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug that should be fixed in version 2.0.1

Comment: Thanks - do you happen to have a source for this?

Comment: Ahh - I updated to 2.0.1 in my main project but forgot and stayed at 2.0 in my test. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

//ugly but works

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"delete from aspnetuserroles from
aspnetuserroles ur inner join aspnetroles r on r.id=ur.roleid inner join aspnetusers 
u on u.id=ur.userid where r.name=@role and u.username=@user",
    new SqlParameter("@role",RoleName) ,
    new SqlParameter("@user",UserName));
```